# nodejs why he is not putting the accesstoken in a cookie at login?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, jwt, expo

I try to learn jwt and refresh tokens and I have some question about.

In a article is this snippet:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // Destructuring username & password from body
    const { username, password } = req.body;
 
    // Checking if credentials match
    if (username === userCredentials.username &&
        password === userCredentials.password) {
 
        //creating a access token
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({
            username: userCredentials.username,
            email: userCredentials.email
        }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: '10m'
        });
        // Creating refresh token not that expiry of refresh 
        //token is greater than the access token
 
        const refreshToken = jwt.sign({
            username: userCredentials.username,
        }, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' });
 
        // Assigning refresh token in http-only cookie 
        res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: 'None', secure: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        });
        return res.json({ accessToken });
    }
    else {
        // Return unauthorized error if credentials don't match
        return res.status(406).json({
            message: 'Invalid credentials'
        });
    }
})
```

Why he is not set the access token in cookie but only the refreshtoken ?

And on mobile like react-native, there are no cookies so how I handle the verify to check if the token is expired ?

Comment: This code lacks the context. But it looks like it presumes that access and refresh tokens are stored in a different way on client side. RT is more sensitive due to its role and is forced to be stored as httponly cookie, which is believed to be more secure than other browser storage (regular cookies, localstorage, etc). AS is just returned with a response and client side is free to choose how it will be stored. Due to its short lifetime (10m) it could be stored in-memory without persistence.

Comment: For the compatibility with native platforms RT and AT could be returned both with a response in addition to RT httponly cookie (web platform). Once you have an idea which security concerns you try to address (XSS, etc), you are free to choose the way it's stored. E.g. in native platform you can use encrypted storage for sensitive data. This RT has relatively short lifespan (24h) so it's less of a threat than an unexpiring one.